# opencv hough circle function

Tags: opencv, hough-transform

I am using this code to detect circle in a video file

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


using namespace cv;



    Mat src;
    VideoCapture capture;
    capture.open("movingBall.wmv");
    capture.read(src);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);


if (!src.data) {
    std::cout << "ERROR:\topening image" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
cv::namedWindow("image1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cv::namedWindow("image2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

while (true){
capture.read(src);

cv::imshow("image1", src);

Mat src_gray2;
cvtColor(src, src_gray2, CV_BGR2GRAY);

GaussianBlur(src_gray2, src_gray2, cv::Size(9, 9), 2, 2);

vector<Vec3f> circles;

HoughCircles(src_gray2, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,
    2,   // accumulator resolution (size of the image / 2)
    5,  // minimum distance between two circles
    70, // Canny high threshold
    100, // minimum number of votes
    0, 0); // min and max radius

std::cout << circles.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "end of test" << std::endl;


for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
{
    Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
    int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
    circle(src, center, 3, Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 8, 0);
    // circle outline
    circle(src, center, radius, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0);
}

/*std::vector<cv::Vec3f>::
    const_iterator itc = circles.begin();

while (itc != circles.end()) {

    cv::circle(src_gray2,
        cv::Point((*itc)[0], (*itc)[1]), // circle centre
        (*itc)[2],       // circle radius
        cv::Scalar(0,0,0), // color
        2);              // thickness

    ++itc;
}*/

cv::imshow("image2", src_gray2);

cvWaitKey(33);
}
return 0;
}
```

The problem I face is that I am unable to detect any circles on my video file despite how much i change to the HoughCircle parameters.

And is there a possibility to create a trackbar to monitor these parameters?

For image, I can see the circle being detected, however it is not the circle I wanted, which is still ok.

Using OPENCV3.0.0 with MS Visual Studio 2013 on Win 8 laptop

Testing Video
https://youtu.be/Bf9chPN1Q8w

Testing Image
https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=5.8ghz+antenna&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=665&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI_OGkk8P9xwIVTxuOCh2P-gcz#imgrc=lGGyH8F4_t0Y2M%3A

Comment: upload sample images please

Comment: in the images there are no circles... from perspective projection those real-circles are projected to ellipses. But houghCircles might work with near-circle-ellipses too, BUT: in all those images (and the video), the circles's colors dont differ much from the background. In your video, in addition there is some motion blur because of the fast movement. Please try to compute cv::canny with thresholds high = 70 and low = 35 (the same that houghCircles uses in your code and have a look how the test images look like in the canny. If the circles are present and well visible there hough has a chance